# JCenter hosts java applications that follow maven convention

Tags: android, bintray

After publishing library on bintray i received one mail from support. Below

Bintray (bintray) has sent you a direct message from Bintray:

Hi,

JCenter hosts java applications that follow maven convention.
In addition to the .pom file, your version should include a binary jar file, a sources jar, and optionally a javadoc jar.
Your files should be under a maven path layout.
(see https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_includingyourpackagesinjcenter.html)

Once those files are added, we'll be glad to include your package in JCenter

Last activity on bitray account showing library released. What's the step need to follow now. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got same Email once . I was trying only to upload library with out sample. Later I changed the format ,  Create a new android project and attach library to sample and pushed it and it got accepted .

Here is a sample library of mine which I created for learning purpose 
https://github.com/Redman1037/MenuDrawer

In bintray account the structure should be like

[image]

it should contain all the below files

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have uploaded the library with sample project for the first attempt and i got this mail.

Comment: does your library has all the files in the above pic ?

Comment: No except .pom and .pom.asc all are there. How to generate that .pom file ?

Comment: I followed this way https://ptyagicodecamp.github.io/how-did-i-publish-android-library-to-jcenter-from-android-studio.html

Comment: i have followed the same steps mentioned on the link. library is not linked to jcenter. in that step i am getting that mail.